# Unable to compile class for JSP HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, jsp

An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /jsp1.jsp
Package.CustomTag cannot be resolved to a type

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

JSP file jsp1.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="/WEB-INF/newtag"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ex:CustomTag/>     // LINE 14
</body>
</html>
```

TLD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">    
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>Example TLD</short-name>
<uri>/WEB-INF/newtag</uri>

<tag>
<name>CustomTag</name>
<tag-class>Package.CustomTag</tag-class>
<body-content>empty</body-content>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Handler class

```
package Package;
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

public class CustomTag extends SimpleTagSupport 
{

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException
{
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
   out.write("This is a custom tag");
}

}
```

Comment: So you have a tag class, which is not on your classpath. Did you add the class in your application when you deployed it?

Comment: I am using netbeans so is there any such need?

Comment: First of all, it was not easy to know that you are using netbeans, because you are not mentioning that anywhere in your question. Second of all, the exception you are getting `/jsp1.jsp Package.CustomTag cannot be resolved to a type` is somewhat specific. When you are invoking your jsp, the `Package.CustomTag` class can't be found. So somewhere along your classpath something is missing, netbeans or not.

Comment: But i had already mentioned the Handler classpath in my TLD.

Comment: There is no classpath in there. Where exactly do you have your class? Is it included with the rest of the application?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific it's within the package named Package in the netbeans project folder.

Comment: And after it is compiled, does it end up in your WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: Yes. WEB-INF/classes/Package/CustomTag.class